# How to set dtypes by column in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, types

I want to bring some data into a pandas DataFrame and I want to assign dtypes for each column on import.  I want to be able to do this for larger datasets with many different columns, but, as an example:

```
myarray = np.random.randint(0,5,size=(2,2))
mydf = pd.DataFrame(myarray,columns=['a','b'], dtype=[float,int])
mydf.dtypes
```

results in:

> TypeError: data type not understood

I tried a few other methods such as:

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame(myarray,columns=['a','b'], dtype={'a': int})
```

> TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()

If I put `dtype=(float,int)` it applies a float format to both columns.

In the end I would like to just be able to pass it a list of datatypes the same way I can pass it a list of column names.

Comment: The argument for `dtype` should be a valid numpy dtype (and structured dtypes are not supported), so the list or dict will not work. A possible way is to do the astype for each column seperately. Or first make a structured numpy array and provide this to DataFrame.

Comment: I knew I could assign each individually in a loop but I am surprised  dtype= wasn't flexible enough to accommodate a list. Thanks for the answer though, good to get confirmation :)

Comment: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4464 is currently an open issue for this (if you would like to do a pull request would be great)

Comment: Just for fun: someone has worked around this using `read_csv`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38524255/6646912 :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of pandas version 0.24.2 (the current stable release) it is not possible to pass an explicit list of datatypes to the DataFrame constructor as the docs state:

```
dtype : dtype, default None

    Data type to force. Only a single dtype is allowed. If None, infer
```

However, the dataframe class does have a static method allowing you to convert a numpy structured array to a dataframe so you can do:

```
>>> myarray = np.random.randint(0,5,size=(2,2))
>>> record = np.array(map(tuple,myarray),dtype=[('a',np.float),('b',np.int)])
>>> mydf = pd.DataFrame.from_records(record)
>>> mydf.dtypes
a    float64
b      int64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 29):

I just ran into this, and the pandas issue is still open, so I'm posting my workaround. Assuming `df` is my DataFrame and `dtype` is a dict mapping column names to types:

```
for k, v in dtype.items():
    df[k] = df[k].astype(v)
```

(note: use `dtype.iteritems()` in python 2)

For the reference:

- The list of allowed data types (NumPy `dtypes`): https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/arrays.dtypes.html
- Pandas also supports some other types. E.g., `category`: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html
- The relevant GitHub issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9287

Comment: I need to use `for k, v in dtype.iteritems():` for this to work.

Comment: This can be changed to `df.astype(dtype)`

Comment: This method fail horribly for some type conversions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54393266/change-type-of-column-to-fixed-with-string-inplace-in-pandas

Answer (score 14):

You may want to try passing in a dictionary of `Series` objects to the `DataFrame` constructor - it will give you much more specific control over the creation, and should hopefully be clearer what's going on. A template version (`data1` can be an array etc.):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1':pd.Series(data1, dtype='type1'),
                   'column2':pd.Series(data2, dtype='type2')})
```

And example with data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':pd.Series([1,2,3], dtype='int'),
                   'B':pd.Series([7,8,9], dtype='float')})

print (df)
   A  B
0  1  7.0
1  2  8.0
2  3  9.0

print (df.dtypes)
A     int32
B    float64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

With Pandas version 1.5.3 is it possible to pass explicit data types:

```
import pandas as pd
data = (['Alex', 10],["Bob",12],["Clarke",11.05])
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=("Name", "Age"),dtype=(str, float))
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution available in more recent versions of pandas (currently 2.X) is to pass `DataFrame.astype()` a dictionary of with column names as keys and the type that the values of the column should be are the values in the dictionary.

Other comments and answers said this was not possible in past versions but can be done at least in 2.X versions.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'some_ints': [1, 2, 3], 'some_strs': ['a', 'b', 'c']},
    dtype={'some_ints': 'str', 'some_strs': 'str'}
)

df.dtypes.to_dict()

>>> {'some_ints': dtype('O'), 'some_strs': dtype('O')}

df = df.astype({'some_ints': 'int64', 'some_strs': 'str'})

df.dtypes.to_dict()

>>> {'some_ints': dtype('int64'), 'some_strs': dtype('O')}
```

Another tip available if you chain together operations which could cause type conversions is to call `.astype` on the output of `df.dtypes.to_dict()`

Example:

```
df = (
    df
    .some_type_changing_method()
    .astype(df.dtypes.to_dict()
)
```

This ensures that your dtypes match at the end and beginning of the chained operations or will raise an error if the types cannot be converted (e.g. nans to ints).

Answer (score -3):

while working with data types, they should be passed as strings.

For example the latter method you followed should be modified as

`mydf = pd.DataFrame(myarray,columns=['a','b'], dtype={'a': 'int'})`

instead of

`mydf = pd.DataFrame(myarray,columns=['a','b'], dtype={'a': int})`.

The `dtype (int, float etc.)` should be given as strings.

Or else as an Alternative method (iff you don't want to pass as strings) 
**import numpy as np** and use
`mydf = pd.DataFrame(myarray,columns=['a','b'], dtype={'a': np.int})`

Comment: you cannot pass a dict to dtype parameter