# Python Pandas, create empty DataFrame specifying column dtypes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is one thing that I find myself having to do quite often, and it surprises me how difficult it is to achieve this in Pandas. Suppose I need to create an empty `DataFrame` with specified index type and name, and column types and names. (I might want to fill it later, in a loop for example.) The easiest way to do this, that I have found, is to create an empty `pandas.Series` object for each column, specifying their `dtype`s, put them into a dictionary which specifies their names, and pass the dictionary into the `DataFrame` constructor. Something like the following.

```
def create_empty_dataframe():
    index = pandas.Index([], name="id", dtype=int)
    column_names = ["name", "score", "height", "weight"]
    series = [pandas.Series(dtype=str), pandas.Series(dtype=int), pandas.Series(dtype=float), pandas.Series(dtype=float)]
    columns = dict(zip(column_names, series))
    return pandas.DataFrame(columns, index=index, columns=column_names)
    # The columns=column_names is required because the dictionary will in general put the columns in arbitrary order.
```

First question. Is the above really the simplest way of doing this? There are so many things that are convoluted about this. What I really want to do, and what I'm pretty sure a lot of people really want to do, is something like the following.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=["id", "name", "score", "height", "weight"], dtypes=[int, str, int, float, float], index_column="id")
```

Second question. Is this sort of syntax at all possible in Pandas? If not, are the devs considering supporting something like this at all? It feels to me that it really ought to be as simple as this (the above syntax).

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately the `DateFrame` ctor accepts a single `dtype` descriptor, however you can cheat a little by using `read_csv`:

```
In [143]:
import pandas as pd
import io
cols=["id", "name", "score", "height", "weight"]
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(""), names=cols, dtype=dict(zip(cols,[int, str, int, float, float])), index_col=['id']) 
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 0 entries
Data columns (total 4 columns):
name      0 non-null object
score     0 non-null int32
height    0 non-null float64
weight    0 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2), int32(1), object(1)
memory usage: 0.0+ bytes
```

So you can see that the dtypes are as desired and that the index is set as desired:

```
In [145]:

df.index
Out[145]:
Int64Index([], dtype='int64', name='id')
```

Comment: Nice cheat! So you're saying that without cheating, my convoluted method really is the easiest way of doing it?

Comment: I think using `read_csv` is the easiest way, it has more flexibility compared with the standard `DataFrame` ctor, it's not cheating except that you're intentionally reading an empty file

Comment: not sure why you zipped the columns and the types. I would have just left it a dictionary for clarity.

Answer (score 9):

You can simplify things by using a dictionary:

```
def create_empty_dataframe():
    index = pandas.Index([], name="id", dtype=int)
    # specify column name and data type 
    columns = [('name', str),
               ('score', int),
               ('height', float),
               ('weight', float)]
    # create the dataframe from a dict
    return pandas.DataFrame({k: pandas.Series(dtype=t) for k, t in columns})
```

This way it should be easier to make an arbitrary dataframe without having to modify multiple locations in the code.

Comment: This solution works very well and is very much easier to read.

Comment: I've used this method with a very minor modification, namely defining column dtypes in a dict rather than a list of tuples and modifying dict comprehension accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the dtype of a DataFrame's column also by replacing it:

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].astype(float)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{'col00':int(0),'col01':float(0),'col02':str('xx')}])
df = pd.DataFrame([], None, df.columns)
print df
```

Comment: I did the first assignment followed by `df.types` and the types were `int64`, `float64`, and `object`.  However after the second assignment `df.types` reported that each column was of type `object` so it appears to me that the types are not preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic function based on @Elliot's answer:

```
import pandas as pd


def create_empty_DataFrame(columns, index_col):
    index_type = next((t for name, t in columns if name == index_col))
    df = pd.DataFrame({name: pd.Series(dtype=t) for name, t in columns if name != index_col},
                      index=pd.Index([], dtype=index_type))
    cols = [name for name, _ in columns]
    cols.remove(index_col)
    return df[cols]
```

Note that `return df[cols]` rather than `return df` is necessary to preserve the order of the non-index columns. Some test code:

```
columns = [
    ('id', str),
    ('primary', bool),
    ('side', str),
    ('quantity', int),
    ('price', float)]

table = create_empty_DataFrame(columns, 'id')
```

Check the `dtypes` and index:

```
table.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 0 entries
Data columns (total 4 columns):
primary     0 non-null bool
side        0 non-null object
quantity    0 non-null int64
price       0 non-null float64
dtypes: bool(1), float64(1), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 0.0+ bytes

table.index

Index([], dtype='object', name='id')
```