# assign dtype with from_dict

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in a python dictionary like:

```
data = {u'01-01-2017 22:34:43:871': [u'88.49197', u'valid'],
        u'01-01-2017 11:23:43:803': [u'88.49486', u'valid'],
        u'02-01-2017 03:11:43:898': [u'88.49773', u'valid'],
        u'01-01-2017 13:54:43:819': [u'88.50205', u'valid']}
```

I can convert it to a pandas Dataframe with:

```
data = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
```

but I am not able to use the dtype parameter of `from_dict`. I would convert the index to a `datetime` of similar first column to float and third to string.

I have tried:

```
pandas.DataFrame.from_dict((data.values()[0]), orient='index', 
                                               dtype={0: 'float', 1:'str'})
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: You are passing `data` to the `from_dict` constructor, right? Because it won't accept a list...

Comment: How about `pd.DataFrame(data).T`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: sorry, I copied from my real code where things are a bit different. fixed: I am passing a dict

Answer (score 15):

This appears to be an ongoing issue with some of the pandas constructor methods: [How to set dtypes by column in pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610592/how-to-set-dtypes-by-column-in-pandas-dataframe)

Instead of using the `dtype` argument, chaining `.astype` may do the trick:

```
pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index').astype({0: float, 1:str})
```

Comment: it would be much better to do the conversion at contruction time. In addition I also need to convert the index.

Comment: @RuggeroTurra yes, there seems to be a bug, so this is a workaround.