# Edit type of column to fixed width string (within existing Pandas dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column of string objects in a pandas dataframe.
I'd like to change them to the a less outrageously inefficient fixed width string type.

There are many SO answers ([How to set dtypes by column in pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610592/how-to-set-dtypes-by-column-in-pandas-dataframe)) that detail how to do this for numeric types:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.Series(["1", "22", "333", "4444", "55555"], name="c").to_frame()
df["c"] = df["c"].astype("int")
list(df.dtypes)  # [dtype('int64')]
```

... but this fails for fixed width strings:

```
df = pd.Series(["1", "22", "333", "4444", "55555"], name="c").to_frame()
df["c"] = df["c"].astype("|S2")
print list(df.dtypes)  # [dtype('O')]
```

The contents of `df["c"]` should end up the same as:

```
print np.array(["1", "22", "333", "4444", "55555"]).astype("|S2")

['1' '22' '33' '44' '55']
```

So.. how to change the dtype of DataFrame column? (without allocating a whole new dataframe -- just want to change that one column)

Comment: What makes you think this is "outrageously inefficient"? Im not following the premise of the question

Comment: Youre saying "inefficient" and then converting to a type with indiscriminate data loss

Comment: Sure -- just to illustrate the example.
Fixed with string (in my case), use up WAY less memory because the string are short (much less than the overhead of allocating a PyObject), and memory stay unfragments, and the data can be efficiently serialized and deserialized in a single operation.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is quite true. If you alter the memory footprint of the underlying array that represents that column, it will no longer have the same strides so will have to be copied to be contiguous?

Comment: print getsizeof(np.array(["aaaa"] * 1000000, dtype="object")) 
print getsizeof(np.array(["aaaa"] * 1000000, dtype="|S2"))

Size is (at least) 4x.

Comment: That wasn't what i was saying. Youre asking for it in place and I'm saying that it must get copied to a new block of memory

Comment: Related: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/5261

Comment: OK -- sure. In mean, modifying the same df. I realize new memory must be allocated. I'm update the question.

Comment: @jpp Thanks. And, facepalm, Pandas, facepalm -- probably two of the most important things for a dataframe library would be efficient storage of data, support for all the common datatypes  :-/

Comment: The reason it's not by default as it is a footgun: many times you have a text column which has some rows which are very very long, but the majority are small, so you can avoid allocating N*longest column bytes. Since most of the time you're not doing string ops (e.g. addition/multiplication) this isn't usually a big performance issue, so better to save memory.

Comment: I wouldn’t expect fixed width to ever by the default - however I wouldn’t have expected the designers to consider it such an uncommon use case as to be opposed to supporting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can [`pop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) the column before re-assignment:

```
In [11]: df.dtypes
Out[11]:
c    object
dtype: object

In [12]: df['c'] = df.pop('c').astype('|S2')

In [13]: df.dtypes
Out[13]:
c    |S2
dtype: object
```

Comment: Ooo.. Mmmm. doesn't work that way for me (22.0). I will try 24.0

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using. For 0.22.0 and 0.24.0, I end up with "c object".

Comment: with: `
df = pd.Series(np.array(['0', '200', '0', '200', '200', '0']), name="c").to_frame() ;
df['c'] = df.pop('c').astype('|S2') ;
print df.dtypes`