# Getting ValueError could not convert string to float - python

Tags: python

Please assist with the below python code. Giving me error.

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Alex'

```
import pandas as pd
data =[['Alex',18],['John',34],['Wick',27]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name','Age'],dtype=float)
print(df)
```

[image]

Should give valid results

Comment: You have `dtype=float` for your columns. What type is `Name`?

Comment: Post *text* not images, even for error messages.

Comment: Specifically, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76180554/843953)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two types of columns (string & float) you have to pass a tuple to `dtype`. A tuple that contains the type of the two columns. Like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name','Age'],dtype=(str,float))
```

[A working example](https://onecompiler.com/python/3zs34m3h9)